# make self hosted WCF dataservice hostname aware

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

In a legacy app I am self hosting a wcf dataservice (net 4.5)

Currently the services runs multiple times on

- http://+:80/tenant1/service | https://+:443/tenant1/service
- http://+:80/tenant2/service | https://+:443/tenant2/service
- ...

Now I wanted to switch to another approach

- http://tenant1.domain.tld:80/service | https://tenant1.domain.tld:443/service
- http://tenant2.domain.tld:80/service | https://tenant2.domain.tld:443/service
- ...

I have the following problem.

Until now I used `HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard` for the binding, which worked for the old approach.

Now If I start two services, requests to `http://tenant1.domain.tld` and `http://tenant2.domain.tld` both get answered by the first started service.

If I change this to `HostNameComparisonMode.Exact` the call to `serviceHost.Open();` blocks my app and the service does not respond to requests.

If I change this to `HostNameComparisonMode.WeakWildcard` the call is not blocking but the service does not respond to requests.

```cs
var serviceType = typeof(MyService);
var baseAdresses = new[] { new Uri("http://tenant1.domain.tld/service"), new Uri("https://tenant1.domain.tld/service") };
var serviceHost = new DataServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);

var contract = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IRequestHandler));

foreach (var baseAddress in baseAddresses)
{
    var securityMode = baseAddress.Scheme.Equals("https") ? WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport : WebHttpSecurityMode.None;
    var binding = new WebHttpBinding(securityMode)
    {
        HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.WeakWildcard,
    };
    serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
        new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(serviceType))
        {
            Name = $"{serviceType..Name}-{baseAddress.Host}-{baseAddress.Port}",
            Address = new EndpointAddress(baseAddress),
            Contract = contract,
            Binding = binding,
        });
}

serviceHost.Open();
```

- tenant1.domain.tld and tenant2.domain.tld both get translated to the ip of my server
- I use url reservations because my service runs without admin privileges. For `StrongWildcard / Exact` I had to add the url acl `http://+:80/service` and for `WeakWildcard` I had to add the acl `http://*:80/service`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to rewrite the URL? If so, there is a URL rewrite module in IIS that can help you achieve this, but it needs to be deployed on IIS.

Comment: @TheobaldDu I am running a self hosted app without iis. The app itself runs an owin webserver on `http://localhost:80/tenant1/` and a dataservice on `http://localhost:80/tenant1/service` which works. Now I want to change this to name based virtual hosts without subfolder. I already can reach the right owin server on `http://tenant1.domain.tld:80/` but not the dataservice on `http://tenant1.domain.tld:80/service` (or If I can reach it, it is always the first one started)